# How return a count(*) of 0 instead of NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have this bit of code:

```
SELECT Project, Financial_Year, COUNT(*) AS HighRiskCount
INTO #HighRisk 
FROM #TempRisk1
WHERE Risk_1 = 3
GROUP BY Project, Financial_Year
```

where it's not returning any rows when the count is zero. How do I make these rows appear with the HighRiskCount set as 0?

Comment: Can you confirm that data exists having Risk_1 = 3 but with a count of zero?

Comment: How could data exist when the count is zero...?

Answer (score 12):

You can't select the values from the table when the row count is 0. Where would it get the values for the nonexistent rows?

To do this, you'll have to have another table that defines your list of valid `Project` and `Financial_Year` values. You'll then select from this table, perform a `left join` on your existing table, then do the grouping.

Something like this:

```
SELECT l.Project, l.Financial_Year, COUNT(t.Project) AS HighRiskCount
INTO #HighRisk 
FROM MasterRiskList l
left join #TempRisk1 t on t.Project = l.Project and t.Financial_Year = l.Financial_Year
WHERE t.Risk_1 = 3
GROUP BY l.Project, l.Financial_Year
```

Comment: Key point. All the other answers so far miss this. What values would be placed into Project and Financial_Year for the rows when the count is zero?

Comment: It's selecting the project and financial year from the master list, so it will display those when the count is zero I guess.

Comment: @JamesJiao: The `MasterRiskList` is something I added to my query as an example; it's not in the OP's query.

Comment: I know.. what's what I referred to.

Comment: @JamieF I didn't miss that, it was not in scope of the question. I actually handled it for all rows containing any combination of project and financial_year

Comment: @t-clausen.dk ?? Your answer was posted about four hours after my comment, eleven years ago. That's why my comment says "All the other answers so far...."

Answer (score 9):

Wrap your `SELECT` Query in an `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT Project, Financial_Year, COUNT(*) AS hrc
INTO #HighRisk 
FROM #TempRisk1
WHERE Risk_1 = 3
GROUP BY Project, Financial_Year),0) AS HighRiskCount
```

If your `SELECT` returns a number, it will pass through.  If it returns `NULL`, the `0` will pass through.

Comment: -1 this syntax is invalid. Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: The syntax is NOT incorrect!  It may not work in every situation, depending on what you're looking for, but for this situation, it works perfectly.  I use it often.

Comment: the error message was copied from studio management. I just added the first sentence. Besides it is not the only issue with your answer. You are selecting columns into a temporary table inside a subquery. Your answer is not salvageable

Comment: Then why does it work so well for me?

Comment: I am guessing in a different example you somehow got to work, you only select 1 column inside the subquery and you are not trying to create a new temporary table inside the subquery. If those conditions are met, it would not return an error as long as the subquery returns 0 or 1 row

Comment: Yes, the original question is about using scalar queries.  That's when this works.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have your 'Project' and 'Financial_Year' where Risk_1 is different than 3, and those are the ones you intend to include.

```
SELECT Project, Financial_Year, SUM(CASE WHEN RISK_1 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HighRiskCount
INTO #HighRisk 
FROM #TempRisk1
GROUP BY Project, Financial_Year
```

Notice i removed the where part.

By the way, your current query is not returning null, it is returning no rows.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Works like charm.

Comment: if a (project, financial_year) combination, eg ('liquidate', 2007),  has no row at all in the table, your query will not return any rows. The SUM just replaced COUNT, not providing other benefit. As the top voted says, we have to start with a valid (required) list.

Comment: @oldpride that is true, but if there is no data for the entire year, do we really want to include any rows for that year - that would be a slippery slope. Besides that doesn't seem to be the question

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.Project, x.financial_Year, 
          COUNT(y.*) AS HighRiskCount
     INTO #HighRisk 
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.project, t.financial_year
             FROM #TempRisk1
            WHERE t.Risk_1 = 3) x
LEFT JOIN #TempRisk1 y ON y.project = x.project
                      AND y.financial_year = x.financial_year
 GROUP BY x.Project, x.Financial_Year
```

The only way to get zero counts is to use an `OUTER` join against a list of the distinct values you want to see zero counts for.

Answer (score 0):

SQL generally has a problem returning the values that *aren't* in a table.  To accomplish this (without a stored procedure, in any event), you'll need another table that contains the missing values.

Assuming you want one row per project / financial year combination, you'll need a table that contains each valid Project, Finanical_Year combination:

```
 SELECT HR.Project, HR.Financial_Year, COUNT(HR.Risk_1) AS HighRiskCount
 INTO #HighRisk HR RIGHT OUTER JOIN ProjectYears PY
   ON HR.Project = PY.Project AND HR.Financial_Year = PY.Financial_Year
 FROM #TempRisk1
 WHERE Risk_1 = 3
 GROUP BY HR.Project, HR.Financial_Year
```

Note that we're taking advantage of the fact that COUNT() will only count non-NULL values to get a 0 COUNT result for those result set records that are made up only of data from the new ProjectYears table.

Alternatively, you might only one 0 count record to be returned per *project* (or maybe one per financial_year).  You would modify the above solution so that the JOINed table has only that one column.

Answer (score 0):

Little longer, but what about this as a solution?

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM #TempRisk1
        WHERE Risk_1 = 3
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT Project, Financial_Year, COUNT(*) AS HighRiskCount
        INTO #HighRisk 
        FROM #TempRisk1
        WHERE Risk_1 = 3
        GROUP BY Project, Financial_Year
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #HighRisk 
            SELECT 'Project', 'Financial_Year', 0
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

[MSDN - ISNULL function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
SELECT Project, Financial_Year, ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS HighRiskCount
INTO #HighRisk 
FROM #TempRisk1
WHERE Risk_1 = 3
GROUP BY Project, Financial_Year
```

Comment: As with the other similar answer, this won't work. Where is it going to get values for `Project` and `Financial_Year` if the rows aren't there to provide them?

Comment: You're right, I realized this about 3 seconds after I posted.  It's times like this I wish there was a way to delete on SO, but I suppose next time I'll take the additional 3 seconds to think before submitting... upvote coming to ya...